# Parity transformation of spinor helicity brackets

Tags: field-theory, spinors, parity, helicity

I'm trying to figure out why a parity transformation $P: (E, \textbf{p} ) \rightarrow (E, - \textbf{p})$ implies $\langle i \ j \rangle \rightarrow - [i \ j]$ and $[i \ j]\rightarrow - \langle i \ j \rangle$, where the angle and square brackets belong to the spinor helicity formalism. Does anybody have a suggestion?

PD: I read somewhere that the parity transformation implies $\lambda_a \rightarrow \lambda'_a= (-i\tilde{\lambda}_2, i \tilde{\lambda}_1)$ and $\tilde{\lambda}_{\dot{a}} \rightarrow  \tilde{\lambda}'_{\dot{a}} = (i\lambda_2, -i\lambda_1)$, where $\lambda_a$ and $\tilde{\lambda}_{\dot{a}}$ are twistors. Honestly, I cannot understand the notation of having a pair of $\lambda$'s. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Read somewhere? Which page?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.00027 Page 20 of the document.